# Most efficient SQL to get the first row in group by, with an ordinal position column (custom sort order)

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

## Using SQL, how to get first row in group by, with an ordinal position column (custom sort order)

Background:

1. Using SQLServer 2019, though **cross platform  ANSI SQL solution** would be better. CANNOT use TOP clause (as must run cross db platform).
2. A parent table (`tb_book`) has many child categories (`tb_linked_categories`), sorted using an `ordinal_position` column
3. Each row can duplicate the `ordinal_position` (values only need be >0)
4. Result: for every parent, get lowest `ordinal_position`, get first `category_id`. This becomes the `default category`. See "Requirements" section

### Data and DDL

Created a SQLFiddle to best demonstrate the issue:

[SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/973706/1)

DDL for table `tb_linked_categories`

```
CREATE TABLE [tb_linked_categories]
(
   [notes] NVARCHAR(200),
   [id] BIGINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [pk_tb_linked_categories] PRIMARY KEY,
   [ordinal_position] INT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
   [category_id] BIGINT NOT NULL,
   [parent_id] INT NOT NULL
)
```

Data for table `tb_linked_categories`

| id | ordinal_position | parent_id | category_id | notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | null |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | expected, parent_id:1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 4 | null |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 1 | null |
| 5 | 4 | 1 | 5 | null |
| 6 | 8 | 2 | 9 | expected, parent_id:2 |
| 7 | 9 | 2 | 10 | null |
| 8 | 10 | 2 | 7 | null |

### Requirements:

For each book, get the first `category_id`. This means get the lowest `ordinal_position`, if there are 3 rows with the same `ordinal_position`, then get the first (or the lowest numbered `category_id` is ok too).

#### Expected result:

| parent_id | category_first_item_id | ordinal_position | category_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 9 | 8 | 1 |

### Problems to solve

A few problems to solve:

1. Can a single SQL Query suffice, with no need for sub-queries or CTE?
2. What is the most efficient solution query?

### Possible solution using a CTE

Here is a working solution using a CTE that is referenced twice

```
;
WITH
   [cte] AS (
      SELECT
         'group by parent, ordinal position' [cte_dev_message]
         , [t].[parent_id]
         , [t].[ordinal_position]
         , MIN([t].[category_id]) [category_first_item_id]
         , COUNT([t].[id]) [category_count]
         , STRING_AGG([t].[category_id] ,',') [category_ids_csv]
      FROM
         [tb_linked_categories] [t]
      GROUP BY [t].[parent_id], [t].[ordinal_position] )
SELECT
   --'get min ordinal position for each parent' [outer_dev_message]
   cte1.[parent_id], [category_first_item_id], [ordinal_position], [category_count]
FROM
   [cte] [cte1]
      INNER JOIN (
      SELECT [parent_id], MIN([ordinal_position]) [min_ordinal_position]
      FROM [cte]
      GROUP BY [parent_id] ) [mins] ON [cte1].[parent_id] = [mins].[parent_id]
WHERE
   [mins].[min_ordinal_position] = [cte1].[ordinal_position]

ORDER BY [cte1].[parent_id];
```

### Full source SQL

Following:

```
CREATE TABLE [tb_linked_categories]
(
   [notes] NVARCHAR(200),
   [id] BIGINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [pk_zxvshd_example1_with_ordinal_index] PRIMARY KEY,
   [ordinal_position] INT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
   [category_id] BIGINT NOT NULL,
   [parent_id] INT NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO tb_linked_categories (id, notes, ordinal_position, category_id, parent_id) VALUES (1, null, 2, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO tb_linked_categories (id, notes, ordinal_position, category_id, parent_id) VALUES (2, N'expected first', 2, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO tb_linked_categories (id, notes, ordinal_position, category_id, parent_id) VALUES (3, null, 2, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO tb_linked_categories (id, notes, ordinal_position, category_id, parent_id) VALUES (4, null, 3, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO tb_linked_categories (id, notes, ordinal_position, category_id, parent_id) VALUES (5, null, 4, 5, 1);
INSERT INTO tb_linked_categories (id, notes, ordinal_position, category_id, parent_id) VALUES (6, N'expected first', 8, 9, 2);
INSERT INTO tb_linked_categories (id, notes, ordinal_position, category_id, parent_id) VALUES (7, null, 9, 10, 2);
INSERT INTO tb_linked_categories (id, notes, ordinal_position, category_id, parent_id) VALUES (8, null, 10, 7, 2);


;
WITH
   [cte] AS (
      SELECT
         'group by parent, ordinal position' [cte_dev_message]
         , [t].[parent_id]
         , [t].[ordinal_position]
         , MIN([t].[category_id]) [category_first_item_id]
         , COUNT([t].[id]) [category_count]
         , STRING_AGG([t].[category_id] ,',') [category_ids_csv]
      FROM
         [tb_linked_categories] [t]
      GROUP BY [t].[parent_id], [t].[ordinal_position] )
SELECT
   --'get min ordinal position for each parent' [outer_dev_message]
   cte1.[parent_id], [category_first_item_id], [ordinal_position], [category_count]
FROM
   [cte] [cte1]
      INNER JOIN (
      SELECT [parent_id], MIN([ordinal_position]) [min_ordinal_position]
      FROM [cte]
      GROUP BY [parent_id] ) [mins] ON [cte1].[parent_id] = [mins].[parent_id]
WHERE
   [mins].[min_ordinal_position] = [cte1].[ordinal_position]

ORDER BY [cte1].[parent_id];
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach starts from the `tb_book` table, and then uses a lateral join to efficiently pick the relevant child. Assuming that column `tb_book(id)` is referenced in `tb_linked_categories(parent_id)`:

```
select b.*, c.*
from tb_book b
outer apply (
    select top (1) c.* 
    from tb_linked_categories c 
    where c.parent_id = b.id
    order by c.ordinal_position
) c
```

Here, the database typically executes the subquery once for each book. With an index on `tb_linked_categories(parent_id, ordinal_position)`, this should be fast, and potentially faster than other solutions (aggregation, filtering with a subquery or with `row_number()`), which require scanning the whole child table.

Here is an [updated version of your fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/777b7e/2) that illustrates the concept.

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks GMB, works a charm on MSSQL (possibly also on MySQL and Oracle by tweaking the row limit clause). Unfortunately I forgot to mention (updated now), that I cannot use the TOP keyword, preference for a cross platform ANSI SQL solution.

Comment: @Rax: you could use a `FETCH` clause instead of the non-ANSI `TOP`. It is supported in several databases (SQL Server, Oracle, …)